# What are the side effects of using mapperDirectoryRedirectEnabled = true and mapperContextRootRedirectEnabled="true" in tomcat context

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat8

Recently Tomcat has released a CVE-2018-11784 (Apache Tomcat redirection issue),and it says my tomcat 7 version which i am using is affected.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1636512
https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/23134c9b5a23892a205dc140cdd8c9c0add233600f76b313dda6bd75@%3Cannounce.tomcat.apache.org%3E

However they also mentioned the mitigation steps that should be done. One of the mitigation steps is enabling the attributes mapperDirectoryRedirectEnabled  and mapperContextRootRedirectEnabled both to true in the context.xml.

Currently we do not use any of the attribute , but as per apache tomcat documentation(https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html)) , Default values of these attributes if not used is as below

1. By Default --> mapperContextRootRedirectEnabled will be “true”
2. By Default --> mapperDirectoryRedirectEnabled  will be "false"

And also tomcat cve mentions that if mapperDirectoryRedirectEnabled  = enabled,
"***If enabled, requests for a web application directory will be redirected (adding a trailing slash) if necessary by the Mapper rather than the default Servlet. This is more efficient but has the side effect of confirming that the directory is exists. If not specified, the default value of false is used.***”

Can you please let me know what are the side effects which might occur when we use the these or enable these attributes ?

Answer (score 0):

> Currently we do not use any of the attribute , but as per apache tomcat documentation(https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html)) , Default values of these attributes if not used is as below

1. The online documentation is for the current (latest) released version of Tomcat. That is `7.0.91` at the time of this writing.

   If you are using any older version, you must consult your own copy of documentation webapp for the version that you are using. Especially when dealing with security sensitive options. Note that the old versions can be downloaded from "Archives" site, as linked on the download page. There exists a "Full documentation" archive (fulldocs.tar.gz) for each version.
2. Those options control what happens when a client requests `http://yousite/yourapp` or `http://yousite/yourapp/yourdir` without a trailing '/' in the URL.

   Tomcat should respond with a `302` redirect to `http://yousite/yourapp/` or `http://yousite/yourapp/yourdir/` respectively.

   The options control where (in the call stack / pipeline) the redirection happens. The pipeline is generally `Connector` (Coyote) → `CoyoteAdapter` → `Mapper` → `Valves` → `Filters` → `Servlet`.

   If the redirection happens in `Mapper`, it means that the `302` redirection response will be sent to the client before any `Valve` takes a look at the request. If you have a `RemoteAddrValve` in your pipeline, it will not see this request and has no chance to reject it.

   The old versions of Tomcat (earlier than December 2015 - earlier than 7.0.66) all behave as if both of those **mapper*RedirectEnabled** options are true.

Comment: My tomcat version is 7.0.90  and one thing which i observed when i enter the requested url in the browser as http://url:port//files and it is redirecting to files.com( files directory is present under webapps/ROOT) .I don't want this redirection to happen .